# Angular 2 how to UT code coverage method existing in directive providers array?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, code-coverage

[Problematic zone is marked in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB2Bj.png)

Can anyone suggest me how to cover the code with the red background? I don't want to get code coverage lower than certain value.